# Перевод фокуса между QCommandLinkButton с клавиатуры

Tags: qt, qt5

Использую в окне только `QCommandLinkButton`.

Столкнулся с проблемой: не могу перевести фокус при помощи клавиатуры(`Tab`).

Мышкой все отрабатывает нормально. В дезайнере порядок обхода установлен. `FocusPolicy` - `StrongFocus`

Как заставить реагировать на `Tab`?

P.S. `Linux, Gnome, Qt 5.9.3`

Comment: а дизайнере Preview сделать, работает Tab?

Comment: Дзайнер, как отдельное приложение, не стоит. Разрабатываю форму в режиме дизайна крейтора.

Comment: а какая разница, Alt+Shift+R

Comment: За подсказку по сочетанию клавиш спасибо! Честно говоря на знал :-(

Попробовал и выяснил, что фокус переключается(поставил несколько других компонент перед и после кнопки), но визуально этого не видно! Кнопка не меняет своего внешнего вида после установки на ней фокуса с помощью клавиатуры. Как с этим бороться?

Comment: даже не знаю, что подумать, может тема в Gnome, как то действует...

Comment: Вот и я тоже не знаю куда кинуться. В общем то не критично, но все же....

Comment: а, стиль какой? Fusion?